# How can i display multiple years of data from 1 project in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, chart.js

So my goal is to have a chart.js, where as labels on the x axis are the 12 months and on the y axis is data per project per year. I want all the years a project has data to, to be displayed as the legend in different colors.

So my thought was, that i have to somehow insert datasets dynamically into my chart.
Or better said "map" the months from the DB to the months on the chart.
But i'm stuck and can't think of a way of doing it.

I really would appreciate your help!

Here's what i have so far:

**queries.php**

```
   <?php

$mysqli = new MySQLi("localhost", "root", "", "monitoring_database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_errno;
}

isset($_POST["project"]) ? $project = $_POST["project"] : $project = "";

$ertrag = "";
$month = "";
$year = "";
$combined_data = "";
$bar_graph = "";

$getData = "SELECT
monitoring_database.systems.display_name AS project,
monitoring_database.systems.name AS ShortName,
monitoring_database.systems.collector_area AS Kollektorfläche,
ROUND (AVG(monitoring_database.heat_meter_values.value)) AS Ertrag,
YEAR(monitoring_database.heat_meter_values.timestamp) AS Jahr,
MONTHNAME(monitoring_database.heat_meter_values.timestamp) AS Monat
FROM monitoring_database.systems
INNER JOIN monitoring_database.heat_meter
ON monitoring_database.systems.id = monitoring_database.heat_meter.system_id
INNER JOIN monitoring_database.heat_meter_values
ON monitoring_database.heat_meter.id = monitoring_database.heat_meter_values.heat_meter_id
GROUP BY project, jahr, monat
HAVING ShortName = '$project'";
$rows = $mysqli->query($getData);
$rowcount = $rows->num_rows;
if($rowcount > 0) {
    while($r = $rows->fetch_assoc()) {
        $ertrag .= '"' . $r["Ertrag"] . '",';
        $year .= '"' . $r["Jahr"] . '",';
        $month .= '"' . $r["Monat"] . '",';
        // $combined_data .= '"' . $r['Jahr'] . '":[' . '"' . $r['Monat'] . '",'. '"' . $r['Ertrag'] . '"}';

    }
}
// Array pro Jahr bauen -> {2019: [], 2018: [], 2017: []}
echo print_r($combined_data);
$ertrag = substr($ertrag, 0, -1);
$month = substr($month, 0, -1);
$year = substr($year, 0, -1);
$bar_graph = '
<canvas id="graph" data-settings=
\'{
"type": "bar",
"data":
{
    "labels": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    "datasets":
        [{
            "label": "' .$project. '",
            "backgroundColor": "#000000",
            "borderColor": "#000000",
            "data": [' . $ertrag . ']
        }]
    },
    "options":
    {
        "legend":
        {
            "display": true,
            "position": "top"
        }
    }
}\'
></canvas>';
echo $bar_graph;
```

Maybe in my while loop in querie.php add a function, that maps months from db to months from chart.js

A small Portion of the **$combined_data** for Project 1 looks like this:

```
 "2017","August","126783","2017","December","222773","2017","November","219508","2017","October","200562","2017","September"
```

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.5.2/materia/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B4morbeopVCSpzeC1c4nyV0d0cqvlSAfyXVfrPJa25im5p+yEN/YmhlgQP/OyMZD" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <select class="custom-select" id="selProject">
                    <option value="IKEA" >Ikea Alexandra</option>
                    <option value="UWC">United World College</option>
                    <option value="DMHS">Desert Mountain High School</option>
                    <option value="MAN">Hospital Managual</option>
                    <option value="FHW">Fernheizwerk Graz</option>
                    <option value="WWA">Wasserwerk Andritz</option>
                    <option value="PRIS">Prishtina</option>
                    <option value="BERG">Fleischwaren Berger</option>
                    <option value="ALAIN">Al Ain</option>
                    <option value="GHS">Gasthaus Schwaab</option>
                    <option value="AVL" selected="">AVL List</option>
                    <option value="GROT">Grottenhofstraße</option>
                    <option value="JUD">Judendorf</option>
                    <option value="BERL">Berliner Ring</option>
                    <option value="OBER">Oberzeiring</option>
                    <option value="COOL">Coolcabin</option>
                    <option value="DIGI">Digicell</option>
                    <option value="BRUE">Brüssel</option>
                    <option value="FKH">Friedrich Karl Höfe</option>
                    <option value="ERLA">Erlaaer Platz Wien</option>
                    <option value="ROES">Rösslergasse</option>
                    <option value="STAD">Stadion Liebenau</option>
                    <option value="MURZ">Fernwärme Mürzzuschlag</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col" id="divGraph">
                <!-- Graph goes here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-d9xgZrVZpmmQlfonhQUvTR7lMPtO7NkZMkA0ABN3PHCbKA5nqylQ/yWlFAyY6hYgdF1Qh6nYiuADWwKB4C2WSw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        // Array pro Jahr bauen -> {2019: [], 2018: [], 2017: []}
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/solid3/queries.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    project: "AVL"
                },
                success: function (bar_graph){
                    $("#divGraph").html(bar_graph);
                    $("#graph").chart = new Chart($("#graph"), $("#graph").data("settings"));
                }
            });
            $("#selProject").change(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost/solid3/queries.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        project: $(this).val()
                    },
                    success: function (bar_graph){

                        $("#divGraph").html(bar_graph);
                        $("#graph").chart = new Chart($("#graph"), $("#graph").data("settings"));
                    }
                })
            });
        });


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

@Edit
So what i currently have is this: To 12 Months the first 12 Data-entries are displayed.
[image]

But i want to have all the data displayed like here:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said, or given us a way to easily see, what your problem is or what your code generates, but it looks as if you are passing "labels" an array with 12 values, and passing "data" a much longer array of 12 x number of years of data for that project within 1 dataset, which shouldn't work.

I think you want to be passing in *multiple* datasets whose "data" arrays only contains 12 values each, corresponding with your 12 labels).  For 1 project/multiple years, "datasets" should be something like:

```
  [{
        "label": "' . $year . '",
        "backgroundColor": "#000000",
        "borderColor": "#000000",
        "data": [' . $ertrag['1975'] . '] // has exactly 12 values
    },{
        "label": "' . $year . '",
        "backgroundColor": "#000000",
        "borderColor": "#000000",
        "data": [' . $ertrag['1976'] . '] // has exactly 12 values
    }...]
```

If that is the case, I would the $ertrag subroutine generate something that looks more like: `$ertrag = [1976=>[123446,123235,345246,123445,123456,...],1977=>[112345,1234567,...]...]`.  Then you could generate datasets very easily.

Comment: Sorry for being unprecise, i've edited the post :)

Comment: To your question "What i want to display"

Comment: I want multiple years of data from 1 project :)